# I am using coverity to analyse node-ts template for a service. What should I use to build it?

Tags: node.js, npm, coverity

Steps:

1. Installed coverity
2. Configured compiler

   `cov-configure --javascript`
   `cov-configure --cs`
3. I am stuck at the build step of cov-build. Yarn is used to run and configure the service. But I am not sure what coverity wants here.

I tried a couple of npm run commands, every time end up getting this:

[WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration
or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.
Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.

I also tried different compilers, but no luck.
What should be done in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a file system capture for Javascript files.  You can accomplish this by running cov-build with the --no-command flag.

```
cov-build --dir CoverityIntermedediateDir --no-command --fs-capture-list list.txt
```

Lets break down these commands:

- --dir: intermediate directory to store the emitted results (used for cov-analyze later).
- --no-command: Do not run a build command and to look for certain file types
- --fs-capture-list: Use the file that is provided to specify which files to look at and possibly emit to the intermediate directory.

A recommended way to generate the list.txt file is to grab it from your source control.  If using git run:

```
git ls-files > list.txt
```

I want to also point out that if you don't have a convenient way to get a file listing in order to use the --fs-capture-list command you can use --fs-capture-search command and pair that with a filter to exclude the node_modules directory.

The coverity forums have some useful questions and answers:
[Node.js File system capture](https://community.synopsys.com/s/topic/0TO34000000QBYnGAO/file-system-capture-detecting)

Really, the best place to look is at the documentation.  There are several examples of what you want to do in their guides.